# Common DRF serializer architecture for CRUD

Tags: django-rest-framework

Lets pretend we have an Django Rest Framework endpoint:

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    content = models.TextField()


class CommentsListCreateView(
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    generics.GenericAPIView
):
    allowed_methods = ['GET', 'POST']
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I want endpoint to work like this:

1. GET just returns list of Comments in format:

```
[{
  article: {id: 1, title: '100 things about'},
  author: {id: 1, name: 'Miguel'},
  content: 'Blah blah blah'
}]
```

2. POST creates a new Comment and returns new comment's JSON in the same format:

`POST {article: 1, author: 1, content: 'Blah blah blah again'}` -->

```
{
  article: {id: 1, title: '100 things about'},
  author: {id: 1, name: 'Miguel'},
  content: 'Blah blah blah again'
}
```

*Note that I post obj ID as param but server returns obj details.*

Is this approach is okay?

Now I have two serializers CommentListSerializer and CommentCreateSerializer for list and view but it looks ugly for me. I bet there are many other ideas better but I cannot get then without your help =) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a perfectly valid approach, especially if you want to spare the clients of performing extra requests to retrieve the related data and the server from unnecessarily parsing the payload just to extract relations' IDs.

If I understood correctly, you're looking for a fancier solution? In that case, might I suggest the following:

```
class ArticleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ["id", "title"]

class AuthorSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ["id", "name"]

class CommentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ["article", "author", "content"]

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = self.to_representation(instance)
        representation.update({
            "article": ArticleSerializer(instance.article).data,
            "author": AuthorSerializer(instance.author).data
        })
        return representation

class CommentsListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
```

I didn't run this code, so there might be some errors, but that's the general idea. I usually prefer using [`HyperlinkedModelSerializer`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer) and [`HyperlinkedRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield) so the clients don't have to reconstruct URLs by themselves, and I resolve them to instances automatically. This often leads me to subclassing `HyperlinkedRelatedField` and overriding its `to_representation` method. That way, I can pass the serializer I want to use for serializing the output as a parameter. A rough draft of this would go as follows:

```
class CustomHyperlinkRelatedField(HyperlinkRelatedField):
    self.serializer_class = None

    def __init__(self, view_name=None, **kwargs):
        self.serializer_class = kwargs.pop(
             "serializer_class", self.serializer_class
        )
        super().__init__(view_name=view_name, **kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        if not self.serializer_class:
            return super().to_representation(instance)

        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=instance.pk)
        request = self.context["request"]
        return self.serializer_class(obj, context={"request": request}).data

class SomeSerializer(Serializer):
    relation = CustomHyperlinkedRelatedField(
        queryset=SomeModel.objects.all(), 
        serializer_class=SomeModelSerializer
    )
```